# How to debug `vite-plugin-static-copy` transform function in `dev`?

Tags: vite, preact

I've just moved from webpack's `copyWebpackPlugin` and having troubles understanding how to debug this plugin's code.

Here's what I have in my `vite.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import preact from '@preact/preset-vite';
import ssr from 'vike/plugin';
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    preact(),
    ssr({ prerender: true }),
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: 'public/assets/icons/favicon.svg', // this is a placeholder string, so we have this script to be executed once
          dest: `path/to/dir`,
          rename: 'filename.pdf',
          transform: {
            encoding: 'buffer',
            handler: async (_content, path) => {
              console.log(1)
              try {
                const response = await fetch(URL)
                const json = await response.json()

                console.log(json)
    
                return await processJson(json)
              } catch (e) {
                console.log(path)
                console.log(e)
              }
            },
          },
        }
      ]
    })
  ],
});
```

While in `npm run dev` none of the `console.log` inside the `viteStaticCopy`, including `processJson`, are being printed out.
The only things I see is `[vite-plugin-static-copy] Collected 1 items.`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vite-plugin-static-copy` apparently runs on demand as a middleware, not ahead of time. You need to fetch (or consume in any fashion) the asset and then you'd see your logs:

```js
// in app code
fetch('/path/to/dir/favicon.svg')
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. Just tested and yes, I saw my logs.